# actionscript dynamic variables

Tags: variables, actionscript

I've got a question about actionscript

E.g. three textboxes with names country1, country2, country3

how do I insert text into those textboxes using dynamic variables

e.g.

a="1"

b="2"

c="3"

["country" + a].text = "AAA"

["country" + a].text = "BBB"

["country" + a].text = "CCC"

Thanks

Comment: What actionscript version are you talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HI,

If you can go, just so I know you have the code in the correct place.

```
country1.text = "hello"; // I assume that works.
```

then you can go.

```
this["country" + a].text = "AAA"; // Then that will work.
```

Answer (score 0):

`this["country" + a].text = "AAA"`

Or something more complex:

```
var countries:Array = new Array();
countries['1'] = "UK";
countries['2'] = "Poland";
countries['3'] = "France";

for (key in countries){
    this["country" + key] = countries[key];
}
```